# Spring boot приложение, get запрос

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, java-11

Изучаю Spring boot, задание: Приложение должно обращаться к внешнему API restcountries.com:
[https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha?codes={code},{code},{code}](https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha?codes=%7Bcode%7D,%7Bcode%7D,%7Bcode%7D)
Из полученного ответа использовать URL хранения флага заданного формата
и сохранять изображение в указанную директорию с названием файла {полное_название_страны}.{формат_файла}.
Пока что написал вот такой код:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FlagService {

    public void getURLFlags(List<String> countryCode, String pathDirectory, String expansion) throws JsonProcessingException {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("https://restcountries.com/v2");
        Mono<String> data = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/alpha?codes=" + countryCode.toString())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(String.valueOf(data));
        try (InputStream in = URI.create(jsonNode.get("flags").get(expansion).asText()).toURL().openStream()) {
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get(pathDirectory + "\\" + jsonNode.get("name").asText() + "." + expansion));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что здесь не так, как это исправить до рабочего состояния и как разбить это все на классы, чтобы соблюдались принципы ООП.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: в чем проблема?

Comment: Код не работает, как надо в задании

Comment: 1)метод .subscribe() у Mono<String> не работает, работает только block(), но нужен асинхронный вызов.
2)даже если я работаю с block(), вызов get("name") не работает, вместо него использовал findValue("name"), выводит только одно имя "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"(При условии, что их должно быть 3, так как входные данные - "gb","pe","col")
3)jsonNode.findValue("flags") выдает null

Comment: если работаю с block(), то он выдает строку, если с subscribe(), то пишет reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber@6233c6c2 вместо строки